# Installing Apache Spark using yum

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hortonworks-sandbox

I am in the process of installing spark in my organization's HDP box. I run `yum install spark` and it installs Spark 1.4.1. How do I install Spark 2.0? Please help!

Comment: `yum install spark_2.0.0-master`

Comment: does that works ?

Comment: No it didnt work it said no package spark_2.0.0-master available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark 2 is supported (as a technical preview) in HDP 2.5. You can get the specific HDP 2.5 repo added to your yum repo directory and then install the same. Spark 1.6.2 is the version default in HDP 2.5.

```
wget http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos7/2.x/updates/2.5.0.0/hdp.repo

sudo cp hdp.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/hdp.repo

sudo yum install spark2-master
```

or
`sudo yum install spark2` (also seems to be doing the same when i tried)

see whats new in HDP 2.5 http://hortonworks.com/products/data-center/hdp/

For full list of repos see https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.5.0/bk_release-notes/content/download-links-250.html