# How do i install latest version of Apache Spark in my Hortonworks Edge Node

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform

I have spark 1.4.1 version installed and if I do `yum install spark`it says latest version installed. How do I upgrade to 2.0? Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Apache Spark using yum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40711924/installing-apache-spark-using-yum)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Just download Spark 2.0.X
- Unpack to your preferred directory
- Update your environment variables (SPARK_HOME)
- Update any other necessary configuration files with other frameworks (like hadoop, or
  zeppelin, etc) if you use any.